# How to display MySQL Query from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am relatively new to PHP and MYSQL, and I have a question regarding outputting MySQL data.

Right so in MYSQL I have the following query:

```
select  organisation as Customer,    
        (select  count(*) from incidentsapril       
            where Service_Type_Priority = 1 and organisation = Customer and (full_resolved_date between '2015-03-01 
00:00:00' and '2015-03-31 23:59:59') ) as numberp1s,     
        (select  count(*)    from incidentsapril        
            where Service_Type_Priority = 2 and organisation = Customer and (full_resolved_date between '2015-03-01 
00:00:00' and '2015-03-31 23:59:59')) as numberp2s,     
        (select  count(*)    from incidentsapril        
            here Service_Type_Priority = 3 and organisation = Customer and (full_resolved_date between '2015-03-01 
00:00:00' and '2015-03-31 23:59:59')) as numberp3s,     
        (select  count(*)    from incidentsapril        
            where Service_Type_Priority = 4 and organisation = Customer and (full_resolved_date between '2015-03-01 
00:00:00' and '2015-03-31 23:59:59')) as numberp4s
from incidentsapril group by organisation
```

Within MYSQL Workbench this query works well and gives me the results I need.  I am now trying to translate this to PHP.

My PHP connection to MYSQL dtaabase works fine, as I have performed some simple select statements.  But this query is a little complex and I want it to display as a table.

This is my current output code

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["organisation"]. $row["numberp1s"]. $row["numberp2s"]. $row["numberp3s"]. $row["numberp4s"] . "<br>";
```

but it doesnt work and i get the error

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sql\index.php on line 47
0 results
```

Any advice or pointers to get me thinking the right way.

Thanks in Advance

$SQL Query

```
$sql = "select  organisation as Customer, 

        (select  count(*) from incidentsapril  

            where Service_Type_Priority = 1 and organisation = Customer and (full_resolved_date between '2015-03-01 

00:00:00' and '2015-03-31 23:59:59') ) as numberp1s,

        (select  count(*)    from incidentsapril  

            where Service_Type_Priority = 2 and organisation = Customer and (full_resolved_date between '2015-03-01 

00:00:00' and '2015-03-31 23:59:59')) as numberp2s,

        (select  count(*)    from incidentsapril  

            here Service_Type_Priority = 3 and organisation = Customer and (full_resolved_date between '2015-03-01 

00:00:00' and '2015-03-31 23:59:59')) as numberp3s,

        (select  count(*)    from incidentsapril  

            where Service_Type_Priority = 4 and organisation = Customer and (full_resolved_date between '2015-03-01 

00:00:00' and '2015-03-31 23:59:59')) as numberp4s



from incidentsapril group by organisation";
```

Comment: can you post the `$sql` variable query string?

Comment: What is the output of `mysqli_error( $conn );`?

Comment: the error emssage suggests that you did not get a query resource. That, in turn, menas your query was not successful. Try @Florian s suggestion and either learn waht went wrong or let us know

Comment: if i use echo mysqli_error ($conn); nothing is returned.  I am getting connection to the server and database without issue.  I can run a simple select statement and display it.  it only fails with a more complex query.  I know I havn't written the query correctly but I need help with why

Comment: echo your query i.e `echo $sql;` and execute in sql;

Comment: thanks Vinnie, that pointed me to my schoolboy error of a spelling mistake, one of the clauses is here and should be where.